# I need to read all A records in DNS domain using perl and Net::DNS, keep hitting walls

Tags: perl

I'm working on a tool to generate SPF TXT records and I am trying to get a loop for scanning the domain for the relevant hosts A records. All I get is just a single entry when I supply the domain name as the domain to check. The other hosts in the domain don't return entries...

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "scanning" and what do you consider the "relevant hosts"? Generally speaking you won't be able to fetch any and all entries in a domain's zone unless you manage the DNS.

Comment: What I am trying to do is read in the domain, which I do own, and then loop over each A record to get all the host names for use in a seperate tool. Is there another way to get all hosts in a domain?

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and it seems that you need to do a zone transfer to get the records, as allowing a random IP to access the whole domain has too many security vectors. So no real way to do what I was wanting... Sorry for wasting time!

Comment: Many DNS hosters allow you to download the DNS zone in some format or have a REST-y or SOAP API that allows you to iterate over the entries.